# caretEnsemble::caretList not working svmRBF, xgboost in r

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to run multiple models with caretEnsemble::caretList. It does not work with svmRBF and xgboost. It does work with svmLinear. Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)
train.control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                           number=5, 
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           savePredictions='all')
df = iris %>% filter(Species!='setosa') %>% mutate(Species=factor(Species))
caretList(Species~., 
        data= df,
        trControl=train.control,
        metric="ROC",
        methodList=c('svmRBF', 'xgboost') )
```

I got error message below:

```
Error in methodCheck(methodList) : The following models are not valid caret models: svmRBF, xgboost
```

Comment: Those models names don't show up in the caret documentation (https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html). I'm not familiar with the `caretEnsemble` package, but I guess you need to specify models by a name that caret recognizes.

Comment: sorry. I made a mistake. it should be svmRadial and xgbTree  thanks